# I need help dropping empty rows and rows with empty spaces from dataframe

Tags: r, text-mining

I am trying to remove all empty rows from my dataframe. Problem is the rows aren't entirely empty, some have one space, other multiple spaces and new lines.

Here are examples:

```
new_tweetsdf[[35]]
[1] " \n                  \n \n"
#second example
new_tweetsdf[[102]]
[1] " \n"
#third example
new_tweetsdf[[188]]
[1] " "
#fourth example
new_tweetsdf[[4671]]
[1] "\n\n"
#fourth example
new_tweetsdf[[11326]]
[1] "\n\n\n\n"
#fifth example
new_tweetsdf[[27137]]
[1] "\n\n\n\n \n"
```

I have tried a few solutions. Firstly I tried removing all rows that are empty and contain no space

```
new_tweetsdf <- new_tweetsdf[rowSums(new_tweetsdf==" ") | rowSums(new_tweetsdf=="") !=ncol(new_tweetsdf), ]
```

But i'm left with empty rows that contain \n or multiple lines. This also makes it difficult to remove rows based on number of characters

I also thought about removing all rows that do not start with a letter

```
new<- new_tweetsdf[grep('^[a-z]',new_tweetsdf)]
```

However this removes about a 5th of my rows, from observation it doesn't seem likely that there are that many empty spaces in my dataframe. This probably also removes rows that begin with a space but actually have letters

Here is a link to the data I am using:
[Data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kF93MKgsvp1CoFdSGV-ZkUbaTTvanI4F)

Comment: You have only one column ?

Comment: Yes, only one column, your code is producing this error message -> Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(^[\n\s"

Comment: It should be double slash `\\s`

Comment: Thanks. Still getting an  error -> Error in new_tweetsdf[!Reduce("|", lapply(new_tweetsdf, function(x) grepl("(^[\n\\s]+$)|^$",  : 
  incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: How did you read the data,  Do you have a `list` or not

Comment: Are you reading it like `df1 <- read.csv(file, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = 1, sep=";")`

Comment: reading it directly from Twitter API, converting to dataframe then for the purposes of this analysis taking one column->  the_tweets <- tweets_df$text...then clean up and converting corpus back to DF -> new_tweetsdf <- data.frame(text = sapply(tweets_corp, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Comment: Your code suggests it as a `list`, if that is the case, it needs to be processed different

Comment: edited my previous comment

Comment: Looks like you have a list column.  I would suggest `v1 <- unlist(new_tweetsdf$text); v2 <- v1[gsub("[\r\n]", "", v1) != ""]`

Comment: Thanks, done. Still have the same empty rows showing on my dataframe

Comment: Here, 'v2' is another object.  Have you checked on 'v2'

Comment: Yeah. I am referring to V2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all the indices with a simple regex.

```
pattern = "^[[:space:]]*$"
```

This pattern will match all rows which only contain "Space, tab, vertical tab, newline, form feed and carriage return". Therefore we need to invert our result, since we want the opposite.

```
new <- new_tweetsdf[grep(pattern, new_tweetsdf, invert = TRUE)]
```